# Noethers AF+BG theorem for bitangents

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $f\in\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ be homogeneous of degree 4, smooth and let $l$ be a bitangent to $f$, therefore intersecting $f$ in 2 distinct points. 
Let $q\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ be homogeneous of degree 2 such that $\mathcal{V}_\mathbb{C}(f,l)\subseteq \mathcal{V}_\mathbb{C}(q)$.
I want to see that $q^2=f+lh$ for some $h\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ of degree 3.\

I would like to use the AF+BG theorem, but somehow I cant figure out why $q^2\in (f,l)\subseteq \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{P}^3)$ for $P\in \mathcal{V}(f,l)$. I assume it's pretty easy to see but I still got stuck.\

Is the following true aswell: If $f=g^2+lh$ like above is $l$ a bitangent of $f$?
I would assume so, since if $f$ and $l$ vanish, they do so to order 2, and thus there have to be 2 intersection points of $f$ and $l$.

Thx in advance

Comment: Maybe this [mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158456/factorizing-a-quartic-plane-curve-as-f-3f-1-f-22/158473#158473) can help.

Comment: Thx for the answer but sadly this is pretty much the part I dont understand. If $f=q^2+lh$ and $f$ ist smooth, why cant $l$ just be a tangent of $f$?